# PHP/MySQL - How to delete insert if query fails?

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I have this code

```
<?php
class Objekt{
// database connection and table name
private $conn;
private $table_name = "objects";
// object properties
public $id;
public $id_group;
public $title;
public $description;
public $lat;
public $lng;
public $icon;
public $tagsraw;
// constructor with $db as database connection
public function __construct($db){
    $this->conn = $db;
}

function create(){
    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                id_group=:id_group, title=:title, description=:description, lat=:lat, lng=:lng, icon=:icon;
            SELECT max(id) AS id FROM objects;";
    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    // sanitize
    $this->id_group=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id_group));
    $this->title=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
    $this->description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
    $this->lat=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->lat));
    $this->lng=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->lng));
    $this->icon=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->icon));     
    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":id_group", $this->id_group);
    $stmt->bindParam(":title", $this->title);
    $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(":lat", $this->lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(":lng", $this->lng);
    $stmt->bindParam(":icon", $this->icon);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
               
        //$stmt->execute();
    
/* 
      ERROR below here
      Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
      stack trace:
      #0 PDOStatement -&gt;fetch(2)
      #1 Objekt-&gt;create()
*/

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->id = $result['id'];
        echo "$this->id";
                    
        //get tags matches
        $tags = [];
        $this->tagsraw = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $this->tagsraw);
        $tags = explode(',', $this->tagsraw);
        
        $id_tags = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tags); $i++) {
            $query = "SELECT id FROM category WHERE title=" . tags[i];
            
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            
            $stmt->execute();
            
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $id_tags[i] = $result->id;
        }
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($id_tags); $i++) {            
            $query = "INSERT INTO category_object SET id_object=" . $this->id . ", id_category=" . $id_tags[i];
            
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            
            $stmt->execute();
            
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I want to do:

> Insert Object and create a relation to a category_object table over foreign keys id_object / id_category

What I would like to improve:

> What do I have to do to delete an insert if it fails (where should I put a try/catch or something else)
>
> What is wrong with my fetch? I Select the value from max(id) to get the value of my inserted object, why is it throwing an Exception

I have another Warning why is it telling me that

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($id_tags); $i++) {            
        $query = "INSERT INTO category_object SET id_object=" . $this->id . ", id_category=" . $id_tags[i];

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

    }
```

will be deprecated in future php versions..

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(` -> Cross side scripting protection should be done when displaying... also `htmlspecialchars()` is not safe to use without charset to protect against a cross side scripting payload..

Comment: You should really use prepared statements everywhere.

Comment: Remove `SELECT max(id) AS id FROM objects;` and use https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

Comment: Also you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ` to remove the need for looping in PHP..  Which also support JOIN's if needed..

Comment: You cannot execute 2 queries in 1 PDO sql statement. But you don't need 2 queries either, you can get the value you need with `$this->con->lastInsertId()`.

Comment: *"You cannot execute 2 queries in 1 go"*  Talking about mine comment? @jeroen

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, to the OP: There is a `;` before the select after the insert query :-)

Comment: oh ok never mind i misunderstood @jeroen i didn't even notice that..

Comment: Thanks! Do I need prepared statements for queries that run in the background, since there cant be user Input? @jeroen

Comment: @nothingspecial Definitely, there still can be characters in the (valid) data that would invalidate your query. Perhaps theoretically now you only fetch numeric ids, but doing it always prevents mistakes in the future.

Comment: @jeroen lastInsertId worked! I still get a warning that my array tags and the loop integer i are not defined, how is that possible?

Comment: You should try to ask only one specific question and post only the code concering that question, that makes it easier for people here to help you. And then you can ask another question with the (modified...) relevant code if necessary, etc. This is a bit too much to look through.

Comment: `$id_tags[i]` is a typo, that should be `$id_tags[$i]`. Likely causing other issues. You should enable error reporting.

Comment: ok @jeroen I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3783243 oh right, forgot the php syntax, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [transactions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php).

Any insert/update/delete done within a transaction will not be actually executed against the database until you call `commit()`, and you can always roll back the changes, abandoning them in case of failure.

In your code, you should be OK with replacing `if($stmt->execute()){` with

```
try {
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    $stmt->execute();

    // ...everything else from inside the if statement here...

    $this->conn->commit();
    return true;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->conn->rollback();
    return false;
}
```